# Algebra Problem in Korean Mathematical Olympiad

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math, fibonacci-numbers

> Let $a_1=5, a_2=25, a_{n+2}=7a_{n+1}-a_n-6$. Prove that $\exists x, y \in \Bbb{Z} $ s.t. $a_{2023}=x^2+y^2.$

Doing some trials and errors, I found that $a_n=(2F_{2n-1})^2+F_{2n}^2$. ($F_n$: Fibonacci number) Then I tried to show this...

\begin{align}
n=1; \; & a_1=5=(2 \cdot 1)^2+1^2. \\
n=2; \; & a_2=25 = (2 \cdot 2)^2+3^2. \\
\text{Assume.} \; & a_k=(2F_{2k-1})^2+F_{2k}^2, a_{k-1}=(2F_{2k-3})^2+F_{2k-2}^2. \\
n=k+1; \; & a_{k+1}=7(2F_{2k-1})^2+7F_{2k}^2-(2F_{2k-3})^2-F_{2k-2}^2-6.
\end{align}

And I'm stuck...

The Fibonacci Lemmas I know with squares are those below, which I don't know where to use...

\begin{align}
& F_{k}^2=F_{k-1}F_{k+1} + (-1)^{k+1}. \\
& \sum_{i=1}^{k} F_i^2=F_kF_{k+1}.
\end{align}

Can I use these lemmas to this problem?

Comment: If your hunch is correct, you should be able to use Binet's formula to brute force this out.

Comment: Note: You can prove by induction that $F_{2n+3}^2 = 7 F_{2n+1}^2 - F_{2n-1}^2 - 2$, and a similar expression for $F_{2n+2}$. This is related to Binet's formula, because the roots of $ x^2 - 7x + 1 $ are $ [(1 \pm \sqrt{5}) /2 ] ^4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by @CalvinLin's comment.

\begin{align}
& F_1=F_2=1, F_{n+2}=F_{n+1}+F_{n}. \\
\ \\
& \text{Lemma 1. } F_n^2=F_{n-1}F_{n+1}+(-1)^{n+1}. (n \geq 2) \\
& \text{(i) } n=2: F_2^2=1^2=1\cdot2+(-1)^3=F_1F_3+(-1)^3. \\
& \ \quad n=3: F_3^2=2^2=1\cdot3+(-1)^4=F_2F_4+(-1)^4. \\
& \text{(ii) Assume that } F_k^2=F_{k-1}F_{k+1}+(-1)^{k+1}, F_{k-1}^2=F_{k-2}F_{k}+(-1)^k. (k\geq 3)\\
& \text{(iii) } F_{k+1}^2=F_k^2+2F_kF_{k-1}+F_{k-1}^2 = F_{k}(F_k+2F_{k-1})+F_kF_{k-2}+(-1)^k \\
& \quad \ = F_k(F_k+2F_{k-1}+F_{k-2})+(-1)^{k+2} = F_kF_{k+2}+(-1)^{k+2}. \\
&\quad \ F_{k+2}^2=F_{k+1}^2+2F_{k+1}F_k+F_k^2 = F_{k+1}(F_{k+1}+2F_{k})+F_{k+1}F_{k-1}+(-1)^{k+1} \\
& \quad \ = F_{k+1}(F_{k+1}+2F_{k}+F_{k-1})+(-1)^{k+3} = F_{k+1}F_{k+3}+(-1)^{k+3}. \ _\blacksquare \\
\ \\
& \text{Lemma 2. } F_{n+4}^2=7F_{n+2}^2-F_n^2+2(-1)^n. \\
& \text{By Lemma 1, } F_{n+1}^2=F_nF_{n+2}+(-1)^{n+2} \\
& \Rightarrow (F_{n+2}-F_n)^2-F_nF_{n+2}=(-1)^n, F_{n+2}^2-3F_nF_{n+2}+F_n^2=(-1)^n. \\
& \Rightarrow 2F_{n+2}^2-6F_nF_{n+2}+2F_n^2=2(-1)^n. \\
& \Rightarrow (9F_{n+2}^2-6F_nF_{n+2}+F_n^2)-(7F_{n+2}^2-F_n^2)=2(-1)^n. \\
& \Rightarrow (3F_{n+2}-F_n)^2=7F_{n+2}^2-F_n^2+2(-1)^n. \\
& \therefore F_{n+4}^2=7F_{n+2}^2-F_n^2+2(-1)^n. \ _\blacksquare \\
\ \\
& \text{Claim. } a_n=(2F_{2n-1})^2+F_{2n}^2. \\
& \text{(i) } n=1: a_1=5=(2\cdot1)^2+1^2=(2F_1)^2+F_2^2. \\
& \ \quad n=2: a_2=25=(2\cdot2)^2+3^2=(2F_3)^2+F_4^2. \\
& \text{(ii) Assume that } a_k=(2F_{2k-1})^2+F_{2k}^2, a_{k-1}=(2F_{2k-3})^2+F_{2k-2}^2. (k\geq 2)\\
& \text{(iii) } \\
& a_{k+1}=7a_k-a_{k-1}-6 \\
& = 28F_{2k-1}^2+7F_{2k}^2-4F_{2k-3}^2-F_{2k-2}^2-6 \\
& = 4\left\{7F_{2k-1}^2-F_{2k-1}^2+2(-1)^{2k-1}\right\}+\left\{7F_{2k}^2-F_{2k-2}^2+2(-1)^{2k-2}\right\} \\
& = 4F_{2k+1}^2+F_{2k+2}^2=(2F_{2k+1})^2+F_{2k+2}^2. \ _\blacksquare \\
\ \\
&\therefore x=2F_{4045}, y=F_{4046}. \ _\blacksquare
\end{align}